# How to detect or handle with JavaScript (even with the help of JQuery) that the browser blocked a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How to detect or handle with JavaScript (even with the help of JQuery) that the browser blocked a URL?
I want to handle browser URL blocking. Like blocking URL in chrome dev tools.

I make a few ajax requests, then I block one of them with chrome dev tools. how can I detect this action in js ?? how to show a popup for example that says "This URL is blocked by chrome dev tools " ??

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to determine on a website that is actually rendered in the browser,  that the browser blocks a URL on this site?

Comment: I make a few ajax requests, then I blocked one of them with chrome dev tools. how can I detect this action in js ?? how to show a popup for example that says "This URL is blocked by chrome dev tools " ??

Comment: I guess there is no way to detect this. The Problem is that the dev tools intercept the normal network request. And it looks like that this interception send no "error" to the ajax request. Which means the error function will not be triggered.